# How do I run my angular app in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a bucket on GCP and transferred my Angular app but I do not know how to run it from the GCP bucket. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you don't RUN your app on Google Cloud Storage, you simply serve it (it's your browser that run it locally).

Anyway, here how to do that: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website